# fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value on button click

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

i am faceing Error in this Error is(fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value)

```
var souncClick = AVAudioPlayer()

@IBAction func PlayButton(_ sender: Any) {

        do{
            soundClick = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: URL.init(fileURLWithPath: Bundle.main.path(forResource: "Click", ofType: "wam")!))
            soundClick.prepareToPlay()

            let audioSession =  AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
            do{
                try audioSession.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback)
            }
            catch{

            }
        }catch{
            print("Error")
        }
        soundClick.play()

        //optionModel.cartCounr = 8
        let PlayGame = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: GameSectionViewController) as! GameSelectionVC
        //        self.addChildViewController(PlayGame)
        //        self.view.addSubview(PlayGame.view)
        self.present(PlayGame, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

Comment: failed in which line? `instantiateViewController(withIdentifier:)` should have a string parameter but not a class such `GameSectionViewController`

Comment: You are getting crash on soundClick or playGame ?

Comment: Add a exceptional breakpoint from Breakpoint Navigator, +, Exceptional Breakpoint. So that you can get the exact line at which its crashing.

Comment: soundClick in this (soundClick = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: URL.init(fileURLWithPath: Bundle.main.path(forResource: "Click", ofType: "wam")!)))

Comment: Any exclamation mark can crash the code. Maybe it's a simple typo: You mean `wma` not `wam`.

Comment: @MuhammadRehan have you got solution?

Answer (score 2):

There are two possibilities of the crash in this code:

**1:** It seems like you are passing a key `GameSectionViewController` but you have to verify you PlayGame object have the instance you can verify by printing before presenting.

```
let PlayGame = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: GameSectionViewController) as! GameSelectionVC
print(PlayGame)
```

**2:** The second possibility is the URL may be nil so you can also verify its printing.

```
let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "Click", ofType: "wam")
print(path)
```

**NOTE:** **Whenever you are getting `nil` you have to verify by the printing it or by the breakpoint.**

Comment: 2: The second possibility is the URL may be nil so you can also verify its printing.

let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "Click", ofType: "wam")
print(path)

result : nil

Comment: So, You have to verify that the file is in the project?

Comment: Also, Make sure that you are copying your file inside build phases/copy bundle resource in your Xcodeproj file (the blue one).

Comment: @MuhammadRehan Also, you have verified the spelling like extension or name also change `wam = wma`

Answer (score 2):

If the code crashes in the line

```
 soundClick = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: URL.init(fileURLWithPath: Bundle.main.path(forResource: "Click", ofType: "wam")!))
```

it's a **design error**, because the file is supposed to be in the bundle at runtime.

Either the sound file with this name does not exist or the file name / extension is spelled wrong.

I guess there is a typo in the file extension (`wma` vs `wam`). And why don't you use the URL related API of `Bundle`?

```
 soundClick = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: Bundle.main.url(forResource: "Click", withExtension: "wma")!)
```

Answer (score 1):

Make use of `if let` to unwrap `optional values` in safe way. Don't forcefully unwrap option. if the value of `option is nil` then you will get `crash`. And make sure you are getting proper values from the options.

Add `storyboard reference` id if you didn't added. **And make sure the `Click.wam` file present inside the bundle. The file is not present then you will the `nil` while retrieve the file path.**

```
if let url = URL.init(fileURLWithPath: Bundle.main.path(forResource: "Click", ofType: "wam")  {
   soundClick = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url))
}


if let PlayGame = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: GameSectionViewController) as? GameSelectionVC {
   self.present(PlayGame, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please delete your file from project and add again with Option -> copy items if needed and -> create groups and -> target to your project as:[image: Add file]

You can also check by select your file in project and in right panel check target membership is selected to your project or not.

Then use

```
@IBAction func PlayButton(_ sender: Any) {

        //Check filepath exits or not.
        if let filePaths = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "Click", ofType: "wam") {

            do{
                souncClick = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: filePaths))

                souncClick.prepareToPlay()

                let audioSession =  AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
                do{
                    try audioSession.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback)
                }
                catch{

                }
            }catch{
                print("Error")
            }
            souncClick.play()

            //optionModel.cartCounr = 8
            let PlayGame = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: GameSectionViewController) as! GameSelectionVC
            //        self.addChildViewController(PlayGame)
            //        self.view.addSubview(PlayGame.view)
            self.present(PlayGame, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }

    }
```

Please also check Resource name same as your file name and Type is also same with file extension and storyboard identifier `GameSectionViewController` also exists.